# Add a dynamic text box to a power pivot chart

Tags: text, dynamic, pivot, box

Im quite used to using dynamic text boxes with normal charts in Excel like bar charts and pie charts. Even the title can be linked to a cell value in such charts.

Im trying to do the same with Power Pivot charts but it doesnt seem to work.

What I tried and failed:

- Select the power pivot chart
- Go to Format tab > Select Insert Text box from Insert Shapes
- Add the text box to the bottom of the chart
- Select the text box and go to the formula bar and enter the reference to the cell that contains the value.

The above steps lead to nothing being displayed in the text box.

If a modify the steps above a little and do the following:

- Ensure power pivot chart is NOT selected
- Add a text box from the Insert tab
- Select the text box and go to the formula bar and enter the reference to the cell that contains the value.
  This shows the value of the cell in the text box.

But the problem with this approach is that the text box is not "connected" to the chart. If the chart is moved the text box remains where it was and the alignment breaks.

Also, Im exporting the chart to a Teams page using the web part "Embed code" option. I would like to have the text box value also visible in the shared chart in Teams.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!